# How to do validation for unique values in a column in WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, validation, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid that users will add rows. It has a column (Text column(template column with Textbox and cell eidt temoplate)) and a combobx column.

I want to do these validations

1. The text column should not allow duplicate values and should show a validation error.

So lets say User enters

A, Combobox Item 1
B, Combobox Item 1
C, Combobox Item 2
B, Combobox Item 3
E, Combobox Item 4

A, Combobox Item 5 -- This should show validation error

1. the whole data should be unique :

So lets say User enters

A, Combobox Item 1
B, Combobox Item 1
C, Combobox Item 1
A, Combobox Item 2
C, Combobox Item 2

A, Combobox Item 2 -- This should show validation error

I saw the validationRule but that is for Vaidation of cell values in a single row. I couldnot find anything which validates with the existing / previous entered data.

BTW, i am using MVVM for my development.

Any suggestions ?

- Girija

Answer (score 1):

For the first type validation since it was individual cell validation i did it using [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx)

For the Second part i use datagRid.RowValidationRule but since i needed the collection of datagrid with current row I need to somehow pass the Collection to validationrule. So I use this as below :

1. [For Passing parameters to Validation Rule](http://dedjo.blogspot.com/2007/05/fully-binded-validation-by-using.html)

Note : this example above pases static resources and not bindings. But it is a well explained blog.

1. To pass binding collection i used the pattern mentioned in this [blog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18678/Attaching-a-Virtual-Branch-to-the-Logical-Tree-in)

Hope this helps anybody who is looking for a similar issue.

- Girija

Answer (score 0):

Using MVVM, you'll probably want to use [attribute-based validation using the IDataErrorInfo interface](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat) on your row ViewModels.

For the custom validation, you can use the [CustomValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute.aspx) with a personalized validation method.

Answer (score 0):

datatable have this built in :) you can set constraints and you recieve validationerrors.